# Homebrew install - sudo?

Tags: bash, git, macos, terminal, homebrew

I am trying to install Homebrew in my terminal. It first asked me for Password which I typed in (the password I use to login to my computer) and hit enter. Then it comes up with 'Need sudo access on macOS!' - what does this mean? I am already the admin (as far as I know) as this is my personal laptop, noone else uses it. 
I don't understand what else they need!

My aim is to install git but I can't even get this to install first..

Can anyone help, thanks :)

Comment: What is the command you're using ?

Answer (score 2):

Open a new terminal session.

type *sudo whoami*

If it comes back with root then you have root privileges. You can also check under users and groups to see if you are an admin.

Also try running it again but using sudo first. You can also type *sudo !!* and that will run the previous command as sudo.

Answer (score 2):

1. Run `sudo visudo`
2. Enter you password one last time
3. In the editor, search for `%admin`
4. The line probably looks like this:

   ```
   %admin      ALL = (ALL) ALL
   ```
5. Change it to this:

   ```
   %admin      ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
   ```
6. Save and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: This resolved my issue - black magic!

Answer (score 0):

If your macos account is in fact an Admin account, its password should be accepted by `sudo`.

See also [this AskDifferent answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/106429/263076).

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution

in the terminal type first

```
sudo su
```

1. Type the password
2. Install homebrew

Answer (score 0):

So it's October 2022 and I came across the sudo messages AND I'm only running Catalina:

1. Go to this link: https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/ to work out which version of Xcode is compatible with your macOS.
2. Sign in to your Apple Developer account and go to this page: https://developer.apple.com/download/all/. Keeping looking down the page till you come across your Xcode version but don't download Xcode just download "Command Line Tools for Xcode" with the same version number as as the compatible Xcode. These tools are a much smaller size than the Xcode file and this is really what Homebrew is looking for.
3. Run the downloaded installer for "Command Line Tools for Xcode".
4. Now run the script available on the Homebrew website: https://brew.sh, the current script is:

   `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`

This ran for me without any errors at all.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Just export this variable before the install...

```
$ export NONINTERACTIVE=1
$ /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

... the install script no longer asks for the password and uses passwordless sudo - as in e.g. the default Amazon Linux config.

Answer (score -1):

To use a command as an admin, you need to use `sudo` before any command, even if you're already admin.

Comment: FYI I downvoted, not because this is not true, but because it’s not useful here. Homebrew’s install script asks for `sudo` access for some operations, but the script itself should *not* be ran using `sudo`.

Comment: Again: no. It’ll even abort itself if you try do so: https://github.com/Homebrew/install/blob/006ab421b2cff87a07d92241e5cdc3cdcd08253e/install.sh#L249