# Hombrew installation issue on macos Big Sur

Tags: macos, unix, homebrew

Trying to install homebrew in my new corporate pc.
facing this issue-

```
el$ /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
==> Checking for `sudo` access (which may request your password)...
Password:
Need sudo access on macOS (e.g. the user el needs to be an Administrator)!
P87111:~ el$
```

Checked *System preferences->users and group*

Seems like i am designated as an admin.
What could be a possible fix? Thanks.

Comment: Why sudo? The whole point of Homebrew is to avoid sudo.

Comment: I edited the issue. Sorry for the previous one.

Comment: Seems like you are not an admin.  If this is because your company crippled your computer... take it right back to IT and tell them to fix it for you.

Answer (score 1):

*This should be a comment but I don't have enough reputation*.

Take a look at these duplicate posts - [here](https://superuser.com/questions/619498/can-i-install-homebrew-without-sudo-privileges) and another one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61239397/homebrew-install-sudo).

The gist from both the aforementioned posts are as follows (three choices):

##### Choice 1: Install homebrew without root privileges:

1. For this, please read the [homebrew's alternative install instructions](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation#alternative-installs) for further information.

##### Choice 2: Make your user an administrator (using Terminal):

1. For this, first check if your user is an admin or not using `sudo dseditgroup -o checknumber -m your-user-name admin`. The output will be either `Unable to find the user record` or `yes your-user-name is a member of admin`. (If the latter, homebrew installation should work)
2. If the former, you need to make your user a member of admin using `sudo dscl . -merge /Groups/admin GroupMembership your-user-name` (more information about his command has been provided in this [previous post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/268602).

##### Choice 3: Make your user an administrator (using System Preferences):

Go to `System Preferences > Users & Groups & Current User > Check "Allow user to administer this computer"`.

##### Reboot in all cases